# Show $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable and find the value of the integral.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = 2x+3$. Also define

\begin{equation*}
\alpha(x) =
\begin{cases} 
\hfill 1    \hfill & \text{ if $x = 0$} \\
\hfill 0 \hfill & \text{ if $x \neq 0$} \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

**Show** $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $[-1,1]$ and determine the value of $\int_{-1}^{1} fd\alpha(x)$.

My thoughts:

Look at the Riemann-Stieltjes sum over an arbitrary partition $P$, given by $S(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{P} f(t_k)*(\alpha(x_k)-\alpha(x_{k-1}))$. Notice that $\alpha(x_k) = 0$ for all $k$ unless $x_k = 0$ for some $k$. This means that if our partition $P$ does not contain the point $x = 0$ then the sum $S(P,f,\alpha) = 0$. So assume $P$ contains $x = 0$. Then all but two of terms equal zero and we have 
\begin{align*}
S(P,f,\alpha) &= f(t')*(\alpha(0)-\alpha(x_{k-1})) + f(t'')*(\alpha(x_{x+1})-\alpha(0)) \\
&= f(t') - f(t'') \\
&= 2(t' - t'') 
\end{align*}
where 
$t' < 0$ and $t'' > 0$.

I also considered using the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing and  $\text{min}_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} f(x) = 1$, $\text{max}_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} f(x) = 5$ which means $t'-t''$ is in the worse case $(1-5)$ so  $|S(P,f,\alpha)| \leq |2*(1-5)| = 8$.

We want to find a value (the integral), $I \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall \epsilon$ and $\forall P$ which refine some $P_\epsilon$ we have: $|S(P,f,\alpha)-I| < \epsilon$ for all choice of partition tags, $\{t_k\}$. This will also prove $f$ is R-S integrable.

I feel like we can consider a partition so fine that $t'$ and $t''$ are arbitrarily close to $0$ so that our integral is zero, but I don't know whether that's true or how to show that.

Comment: What definition are you using for RS-integrable function?

Comment: It seems that your problem is a direct consequence of the following  **THEOREM.** If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\alpha$ is a function of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ then the integral $$\int_a^bfd\alpha$$ exists. This result is standard in Stieltjes-type integrals. For instance, see the book of Wheeden, entitled "Measure and Integral: An Intro to Real Analysis", p.27.

Comment: To prove it directly, just choose $$P_\epsilon = \left\{-1, -\frac \epsilon 4, \frac \epsilon 4, 1\right\}$$ Any refinement $P$ of this partition will have $|S(P,f,\alpha)| \le \epsilon$